# vue-cli default unit tests "Unexpected token {" error

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, vue-cli

I haven't really touched the config file created by `vue-cli` for unit tests, this files being:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  snapshotSerializers: ['jest-serializer-vue'],
  testMatch: ['**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
};
```

And yet, when trying to run the following test with `npm run test:unit`:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import App from '@/App.vue';

describe('App.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message';
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

> back-admin/tests/unit/app.spec.js:1
>      ({"Object ":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

As if `babel` was not able to parse the import statement (specifically the `{`).

What seems to be causing this problem?

Comment: Seems you've mixed up node style exports (`module.exports`) with es6 style imports (`import`). I.e., node style: `module.exports` & `require`; es6 style: `import` & `export`.

Comment: How so? I'm only using ES6 import statements and these seem to be the issue

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57175730

Answer (score 0):

I just asked a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993336/vue-cli-plugin-to-add-jest-test-runner-doesnt-transpile-js-files) ( there is an answer in that one towards the bottom ).

I see in your `jest.config.js` file, you have `'^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',` which should definitely pick up the file. Clearly babel isn't doing it's thing, even though you told it to.

I solved this by adding the extension to the already in place transform option for `jsx`, which would look like this: `'^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest'`.

If that doesn't work for your instance, I would try to make sure all your dependencies are good. The list needed being something like:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.9.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
```

Hopefully adding the `js` works!